# pdb for ASP.NET core security debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

As far as I know, in order to debug and make breakpoint for reference library, pdb file is required.

I'd like to do it with [asp.net core security](https://github.com/aspnet/Security) nuget package but pdb seems not provided.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the source code on GitHub and compile it: https://github.com/aspnet/Security
It's working like a charm.

Comment: I am compiling the code but I get an error when loading the pdb: "A matching symbol file was not found in this folder".